# getJson function dosn't work for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with getJson function when I want to execute it from a click listener - everything is executed in the listener apart from getJson function, so nothing whitin getJson function is executed for some reason. Would anyone help me with it? I am using Codeigniter PHP framework which is new for me if that makes any difference.

```
$("#arrowRight").click(function () {
    alert("pre"); // this works
    $.getJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1", function (data) {
        alert("post");
        $.each(data["results"], function (i, val) {
            if (!charactersLoaded.includes(val["name"])) {
                charactersLoaded.push(val["name"]);
            }
        });
        totalPagesLoaded++;
        if (data["next"] != null) {
            totalPagesToLoad++;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Could you please add any errors in the javascript console to the question? Or if you have no errors, let us know. Usually you can inspect a webpage and see the javascript console with `command-option-j` or `control-shift-j`, or right-click the page and click `Inspect Element`, depending on your platform and browser.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine:

```
const charactersLoaded = [];
let totalPagesLoaded = 0;
let totalPagesToLoad = 0;

$("#arrowRight").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1", function (data) {
        $.each(data["results"], function (i, val) {
            if (!charactersLoaded.includes(val["name"])) {
                charactersLoaded.push(val["name"]);
            }
        });

        totalPagesLoaded++;

        if (data["next"] !== null) {
            totalPagesToLoad++;
        }
      
      $('#results').html(charactersLoaded.join(', '));
    });
})
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/phpist/pen/jOqOKwM) to quickly check it out ;)